# How do I correctly receive UDP datagram packets?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am setting up a windows service that simply opens a UDP port and prints whatever it receives to a log file. My problem is however that while the service opens the port, I never receive anything. I am sending UDP packets from a UDP sender android app. The phone sending the packets is on my home Wi-fi network (as well as the pc that the service is running on). The service name is myShutdownService. I've tried stopping and starting the service again but that doesn't help.

Service.cs code:

```
namespace myShutdownService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            UDPSocket s = new UDPSocket();
            string ip = UDPSocket.GetLocalIPAddress();
            int port = 2700;

            s.Server(ip, port);
            s.WriteToFile("Opening server socket on  " + ip + ":" + port );

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            UDPSocket s = new UDPSocket();
            s.WriteToFile(" STOPPING SERVICE");
        }
    }
}
```

my UDP Socket class:

```
namespace myShutdownService
{
    public class UDPSocket
    {
        private Socket _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        private const int bufSize = 8 * 1024;
        private State state = new State();
        private EndPoint epFrom = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        private AsyncCallback recv = null;

        public class State
        {
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
        }

        public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
        }

        public void Server(string address, int port)
        {
            _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), port));
            Receive();
        }

        public void Client(string address, int port)
        {
            _socket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(address), port);
            Receive();
        }

        public void Send(string text)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            _socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, (ar) =>
            {
                State so = (State)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytes = _socket.EndSend(ar);
                WriteToFile("SEND: " + text);
            }, state);
        }

        private void Receive()
        {
            _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, bufSize, SocketFlags.None, ref epFrom, recv = (ar) =>
            {
                State so = (State)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytes = _socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epFrom);
                _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(so.buffer, 0, bufSize, SocketFlags.None, ref epFrom, recv, so);
                WriteToFile("RECV: " + epFrom.ToString() + " message: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, bytes));
            }, state);
        }

        public void WriteToFile(string Message)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.   
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log file output:

```
Opening server socket on  192.168.56.1:2700
 STOPPING SERVICE
Opening server socket on  192.168.56.1:2700
```

My Windows resource monitor
[image: My Windows resource monitor]

My ipconfig
[image: My ipconfig]

My Windows services manager
[image: My Windows services manager]